# how do i get a GDAL(using gdalwarp) clipped layer projected in pseudo mercator ESPG:3857 to not be shifted?

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip, rasterization

how do i get a GDAL rasterized layer projected in pseudo mercator ESPG:3857 to not be shifted ?
i have a vector layer projected in ESPG:3857,after rasterizing using this command:

```
gdal_rasterize -a_nodata -999 -te xMin yMin xMax yMax -a theField -tr 10 10 -l LayerName -co TFW=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW  VectorLayerPath outPutFilePath
```

the rasterization is perfect, but when i clip using this command:

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata -999 -q -cutline theMaskVectorLayerPath -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff inputrasterPath outPutRasterPath
```

the raster is shifted then clipped and the result is wrong.
is this happening to anybody else using pseudo mercator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the same error when clipping to Pseudo mercator. It might have something to do with the special treatment of mercator projection on a sphere.

Try any other CRS when clipping to avoid the bug. You can reproject afterwards back to EPSG:3857 if necessary.

It might help to set -s_srs and -t_srs explicitely to EPSG:3857 in both command lines, but I'm not sure that it helps.

Comment: i tried to set -s_srs and -t_srs but it doesn't help.Andre i have to redefine CRS or re-project the layers?

Comment: There is not much to redfine on Pseudo Mercator. Try the CRS of your UTM zone as -t_srs for raster and vector files.